# C++ template with pair and static function

Tags: c++, templates, stl

On my last exam I have to write some code to make that main will be compilable. But after exam I spend a lot of time and I don't have idea what I should add into function test_value. I know, that test_value should be static, but I have no idea what I suppose to return.

Can anyone give me hint what to do with this problem?

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

typedef int Int;

template <typename T>
class ptr
{
public:
    T val;
    ptr(void* a){}
    static T test_value(){
//what exactly should be there?
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::pair<int,int>* a = new std::pair<int,int>;
    std::cout<<a->first;
    typedef ptr<std::pair<Int,Int> > TestType;
    TestType t1 = TestType(new TestType::test_value());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a trick question. In order for `new TestType::test_value()` to compile, you need `TestType::test_value` to be a *type* rather than a *function*. Then the *new-expression* will create an object of that type, and `()` is the initializer for the object.

It doesn't matter much what type `TestType::test_value` is; you can use `int` for example. It just needs to be something that can be initialized with `()`.

```
typedef int test_value;
```

However, you wouldn't be able to use `void`, a reference type, or a class type with no default constructor. You also couldn't use a cv-qualified type, because then the pointer to it couldn't be converted to `void*`, which is necessary for invoking the `ptr` constructor.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/781cf8f871f6f1a7

Comment: if TestType::test_value is an int typedef, how do you expect TestType(new int()) to compile?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The constructor takes `void*`, so you can convert some other pointer type to it.

Comment: I just have a mental block on seeing the expression "new int()". Just have a mental block on calling a constructor for "int".